# What are the Corine Land Cover Codes?

Tags: qgis, legend, land-cover

I'm working with Corine Land Cover Map 2012 in QGIS. I can't find any information about the color code. Values range from 0 to 255 but there's no indication which value stands for which land cover type.

Comment: page 59 https://www.eea.europa.eu/publications/COR0-landcover (pdf)

Comment: there is also a spreadsheet [here](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2000-clc2000-100-m-version-9-2007/corine-land-cover-2000-classes-and-rgb-color-codes/clc2000legend.xls) with the land cover codes and their corresponding RGB color codes as defined by the EEA and a CSV version [here](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2006-raster-1/corine-land-cover-classes-and/clc_legend.csv/at_download/file)

Comment: @Mapperz those 14 categories do unfortunately not correspond to the colors in QGIS.

Comment: @dmci the spreadsheet seems to fit. Thanks. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a spreadsheet available [here](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2000-clc2000-100-m-version-9-2007/corine-land-cover-2000-classes-and-rgb-color-codes/clc2000legend.xls) with the land cover codes and their corresponding RGB color codes as defined by the EEA and a CSV version 
[here](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/corine-land-cover-2006-raster-1/corine-land-cover-classes-and/clc_legend.csv/at_download/file). For completeness, the clc codes and RGB color codes are included below.

You'll also find useful information about using CLC data in QGIS [here](https://anitagraser.com/2012/06/17/open-data-for-physical-maps/).

```
CLC_CODE    R-G-B

111         230-000-077
112         255-000-000
121         204-077-242
122         204-000-000 
123         230-204-204
124         230-204-230
131         166-000-204
132         166-077-000
133         255-077-255
141         255-166-255
142         255-230-255
211         255-255-168
212         255-255-000
213         230-230-000
221         230-128-000
222         242-166-077
223         230-166-000
231         230-230-077
241         255-230-166
242         255-230-077
243         230-204-077
244         242-204-166
311         128-255-000
312         000-166-000
313         077-255-000
321         204-242-077
322         166-255-128
323         166-230-077
324         166-242-000
331         230-230-230
332         204-204-204
333         204-255-204
334         000-000-000
335         166-230-204
411         166-166-255
412         077-077-255
421         204-204-255
422         230-230-255
423         166-166-230
511         000-204-242
512         128-242-230
521         000-255-166
522         166-255-230
523         230-242-255
999 
990 
995         230-242-255
```

Comment: Can you list them here (in case the links become dead urls in the future please)

Answer (score 4):

I've created a color map for QGIS. In the raster properties use the render type "Singleband pseudocolor" and load the following color map from a text file:

```
# CORINE Land Cover Classes
INTERPOLATION:EXACT
111,230,0,77,255,Continuous urban fabric
112,255,0,0,255,Discontinuous urban fabric
121,204,77,242,255,Industrial or commercial units
122,204,0,0,255,Road and rail networks and associated land
123,230,204,204,255,Port areas
124,230,204,230,255,Airports
131,166,0,204,255,Mineral extraction sites
132,166,77,0,255,Dump sites
133,255,77,255,255,Construction sites
141,255,166,255,255,Green urban areas
142,255,230,255,255,Sport and leisure facilities
211,255,255,168,255,Non-irrigated arable land
212,255,255,0,255,Permanently irrigated land
213,230,230,0,255,Rice fields
221,230,128,0,255,Vineyards
222,242,166,77,255,Fruit trees and berry plantations
223,230,166,0,255,Olive groves
231,230,230,77,255,Pastures
241,255,230,166,255,Annual crops associated with permanent crops
242,255,230,77,255,Complex cultivation patterns
243,230,204,77,255,Land principally occupied by agriculture with significant areas of natural vegetation
244,242,204,166,255,Agro-forestry areas
311,128,255,0,255,Broad-leaved forest
312,0,166,0,255,Coniferous forest
313,77,255,0,255,Mixed forest
321,204,242,77,255,Natural grasslands
322,166,255,128,255,Moors and heathland
323,166,230,77,255,Sclerophyllous vegetation
324,166,242,0,255,Transitional woodland-shrub
331,230,230,230,255,Beaches dunes sands
332,204,204,204,255,Bare rocks
333,204,255,204,255,Sparsely vegetated areas
334,0,0,0,255,Burnt areas
335,166,230,204,255,Glaciers and perpetual snow
411,166,166,255,255,Inland marshes
412,77,77,255,255,Peat bogs
421,204,204,255,255,Salt marshes
422,230,230,255,255,Salines
423,166,166,230,255,Intertidal flats
511,0,204,242,255,Water courses
512,128,242,230,255,Water bodies
521,0,255,166,255,Coastal lagoons
522,166,255,230,255,Estuaries
523,230,242,255,255,Sea and ocean
```