# Extract Corine Codes from QGIS to an .csv

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, csv, color

I'm doing a project and I need to extract the Corine Codes to a csv accordingly to a set of points. I have already mapped these points on QGIS in a .csv format (with latitude and longitude) and I would like to add a new column to this .csv with the Corine codes of the corresponding points.

Comment: These codes? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243940/what-are-the-corine-land-cover-codes

Comment: yes, can i extract them to a .csv with the coordinates on the map? I already have the corine colors on the map .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sample Raster Values](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgisrastersampling):

> Extracts raster values at the point locations. If the raster layer is
> multiband, each band is sampled.
>
> The attribute table of the resulting layer will have as many new
> columns as the raster layer band count.

Then right-click the result and export as csv

[image]